# php foreach in foreach looping

Tags: php, loops, foreach, file-get-contents

I want to extrect all usernames and passwords each from his file and output it nicely.
I wrote a code on my appserv 2.5.1 on my computer but only the last loop gave the username output.
Tested the code on other machines and it worked perfectly.
Dont know what is the problem ...

usernames.txt content :

```
user1
user2
user3
```

passwords.txt content :

```
pass1
pass2
pass3
```

script content :

```
$usernames = explode("\n", file_get_contents("usernames.txt"));
$passwords = explode("\n", file_get_contents("passwords.txt"));

foreach( $usernames as $username )
{
    foreach( $passwords as $password )
    {
        echo $username.":".$password."\n";
    }
}
```

output :

```
:pass1
:pass2
:pass3
:pass1
:pass2
:pass3
user3:pass1
user3:pass2
user3:pass3
```

Comment: You should start by debugging. Try to `var_dump($usernames)` and see if it contains what it is supposed to contain.

Comment: You have a logic fault. Use only one loop. By using a loop inside a loop you get n*m cycles [n=count usernames; m=count passwords]. What you want is only n cycles (or m).

Comment: You really want to display a full matrix of every combination of usernames/passwords from these files? 'Cause that's what this code is set up to do. I suspect you're trying to display just the username and the password associated with it. If so, I'd suggest using one `for` loop. I'd also suggest that you consider not storing usernames and passwords in separate text files... why not store in a database, or if absolutely necessary, in a file separated by a delimiter (e.g., a CSV file). That way, you'd make sure the usernames and passwords were always stored together properly.

Comment: each array seperretaly working fine with the foreach loop and contatin what is supposed to conatin. i need the code to work like it designed i have my reasons ... no database i am running it from localhost and need it to be in seperate files because this is just a couple of lines of a really big code ...

Comment: Ok maybe they work fine separately. But did you try `var_dump()`? Because your code works perfectly fine, the problem might be with the `explode()`. It is possible than the line separator is a \r\n instead of a \n. That would explain why it works on some machines and not others.

Comment: you are a genius !!! "\r\n" solve it ...

Answer (score 7):

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($usernames) && $i<count($password); $i++) {
    echo $usernames[$i].':'.$passwords[$i];
}
```

But $password[x] must be related to $usernames[x]

Comment: It seems a lot more logical. But I am not sure it addresses the OP's concern, if usernames are not displaying using a `foreach`, why would they show up with a `for`?

Comment: You have blank lines on your files... you can add something like if ($usernames[$i] == '') continue;

Answer (score 1):

After debugging with the post author, I guessed that the problem was with the line return character. Using a `\r\n` fixed the problem:

```
$usernames = explode("\n\r", file_get_contents("usernames.txt"));
$passwords = explode("\n\r", file_get_contents("passwords.txt"));
```

For reference, please note that it is **very** important **not** to assume your input data is right. If you see that something is wrong and it points obviously to a mistake you made previously (in that case it is clearly not the foreach function that is buggy, but the array), then you need to swallow your pride and debug your own code. I have been programming PHP for 10 years, and I still have to remember that every single day.

Answer (score 1):

There's always those that will say you don't *need* it (and you often don't) but I tend to use regular expressions whenever I'm parsing these kind of flat files - there's always some quirky character, extra line-break or difference that finds it's way into a text file - be it from transferring servers, restoring backups or simply user-interference.  You could also make use of `array_combine` in this situation if you'd prefer to carrying on using a `foreach` loop - I know some folks prefer it for readability.

```php
preg_match_all('/\w+/m', file_get_contents('usernames.txt'), $usernames);
preg_match_all('/\w+/m', file_get_contents('passwords.txt'), $passwords);

if(count($usernames[0]) !== count($passwords[0]))
    die('Computer says: mismatch!');  // some resemblance of error handling...

$result = array_combine($usernames[0], $passwords[0]);
foreach($result as $name => $pass)
    echo "{$name}:{$pass}\n";
```

[**demo**](http://ideone.com/RDdRou)